# Magento - Create AJAX endpoint that does not require a key

Tags: php, json, ajax, magento

Im trying to create and endpoint in Magento that can be accessed externally. So I have this in my module controller

```
public function jsonAction()
{
    $json = json_encode(['test' => 'test']);
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($json);
}
```

If I use the below

```
$test = Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("test/test/json");
```

it generates a url with a key on the end and then the url like below:

http://test.app/index.php/test/test/json/key/b4070b1261af163467793da673a4df4a/

This works as expected and the JSON is returned.

The problem is that I need to be accessible from an external site that wont be able to generate the key so Im trying to get it to work just with

http://test.app/index.php/test/test/json

Any help would be much appreciated

Magneto module config.xml

```
    <routers>
        <test>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Test</module>
                <frontName>test</frontName>
            </args>
        </test>
    </routers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a SOAP endpoint and on extension installation I create a Soap user with the correct roles to use the endpoint